# Mvc 3: Populating a dropdown box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I know this is very simple but new to Mvc. I will like to populate a dropdownbox with data
from the GetDescription method such that the dropdown shows the Description and when selected the code is passed as the value.

How can I write the html piece?

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
                {
                    public ActionResult Index()
                    {


                        return View();
                    }

                    public static List<Populate> GetDescription()
                    {
                        List<Populate> myInfor = new List<Populate>()
                        {
                            new Populate{Id=1,Description="Lagos", Code="lag"},
                            new Populate{Id=2,Description="Ibadan", Code="lba"},
                            new Populate{Id=3,Description="Akure", Code="Aku"},
                            new Populate{Id=4,Description="Ejigbo", Code="Eji"},
                            new Populate{Id=5,Description="Oshogbo", Code="Osh"}
                        };

                        return myInfor;
                    }

                }


                public class Populate
                {
                    public int Id { get; set; }
                    public string Description { get; set; }
                    public string Code { get; set; }
                }


                Here is the html
                *********************

                @model PopulateDropDownList.Models.Populate

                @{
                    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
                }

                <h2>Index</h2>



                <p>


                @Html.DropDownList(Model.id, Model.Description, "--Select One--")

                </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also do it like that.

Modify a bit your code:

```
    public static class Helper
{
                public static List<SelectListItem> GetDescription()
                {
                    List<Populate> myInfor = new List<Populate>()
                    {
                        new Populate{Id=1,Description="Lagos", Code="lag"},
                        new Populate{Id=2,Description="Ibadan", Code="lba"},
                        new Populate{Id=3,Description="Akure", Code="Aku"},
                        new Populate{Id=4,Description="Ejigbo", Code="Eji"},
                        new Populate{Id=5,Description="Oshogbo", Code="Osh"}
                    };

                     var result = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
                      var items = from n in myInfor
                            select new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = n.Description,
                                Value = n.Id.toString()
                            };
                foreach (var item in items)
                    result.Add(item);

                    return result;
                }
}
```

Than in your View:
@using YourProject.Helper

```
@Html.DropDownList("AnyTextAsID", Helper.GetDescription())
```

Comment: This is what I got. CS0103: The name 'GetDescription' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @user2320476 I edited my answer. Include this code in static class and call it on class level.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your view:

```
@{
    Dictionary<string, string> populate = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        populate.Add("Lagos", "lag");
        populate.Add("Ibadan", "lba");
        populate.Add("Akure", "aku");
        populate.Add("Ejigbo", "eji");
        populate.Add("Oshogbo", "osh");
}
@Html.DropDownList("myinfo", new SelectList(populate.ToList(), "Value", "Key", "Lagos"), new { id = "Populate" })
```

Comment: Thanks. This does not work. CS0117: 'PopulateDropDownList.Models.Populate' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'